# SPSecurityEventReceiver - when user is added directly to the site

Tags: event-receivers

Thanks for your help. I am trying to implement a notification mechanism where in an email is sent to the site owner when a user is added. This works great with SPSecurityEventReceiver. However, the problem is that it only works when adding to a SPGroup. Is there an event for when the users are added to the site directly without any SPGroup?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're referring to assignment of permissions directly to the user.

In that case you can override the `SPSecurityEventReceiver.RoleAssignmentAdded` method.

Comment: Thanks Slaven. But from my understanding that event only fires if inheritance has been broken. During my tests even the event did not fire when I added the user directly.

Comment: Can you describe what does 'add the user directly' mean?